# Injecting EJB in struts2 action?

Tags: dependency-injection, struts2, annotations, ejb-3.0

Am using struts2 , EJB 3.0 ... 
My requirement is to call the EJB layer from struts2 action class . 
I hope there are two ways in achieving this :

```
1.Using @EJB annotation in Action class
2.Using JNDI look up
```

I tried both , 
 but the problem with `JNDI lookup` is , eventhough am using correct naming , am getting `NameNotFoundException` . So the ultimately , my team moved to other method which is using `@EJB` annotation .

But when am using `@EJB` annotation am getting null out of it , I think  its not injected :

am getting the `NullPointerException`

code :

```
 @EJB(mappedName="BeanLocal/local")
    BeanLocal bean ;
```

Can any one suggest me what i have to do further ...
Also if there is anylink in SOF , please do refer me as i found nothing related to this

Comment: The CDI plugin is likely the "best" approach, but you can also do it manually, a la http://longsystemit.com/javablog/?p=40.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the traditional dependency injection in Struts 2 action classes because actions aren't managed. However there is a way to achieve this by using the [CDI plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.3/docs/cdi-plugin.html) or [Guice](http://www.tzavellas.com/techblog/2007/07/03/using-dependency-injection-in-struts2-for-stateless-ejbs-part-1/).
You can also use JNDI look up but the syntax depends on your server. Your best option is to check the documentation according to what you have ([JBoss 7.1](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI+Reference), [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html)...)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and here is how I solved it.

As Shinosha said, the @EJB annotation will not work since the action classes are managed by the Struts container.

In order to use JNDI lookup, I had to make the bean @Remote and specify a mappedName. Then the code is as follows (it depends on the server your are using, in my case Weblogic):

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
MyBean bean= (MyBean) ctx.lookup("MyBeanMappedName#myapp.MyBean");
```

The lookup string should be the fully qualified name of the bean.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote following interceptors to solve this issue. Have a look and share any feedback you may have :

http://gauravwrites.blogspot.com/2014/11/ejb-injection-in-struts2-interceptor.html